# Why is Get-MobileDevice with a -Filter using a variable not finding anything?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Any help would be appreciated because as far as I can tell this should work.  If I hard code the text the variable $fname contains it finds results but if I use the variable it finds nothing.  I even ran $fname.Trim() to ensure no extra spaces on the variable.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Write-Host $fname
Todd

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-MobileDevice -Filter {UserDisplayName -Like "*$fname*"}

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-MobileDevice -Filter {UserDisplayName -Like "*Todd*"}


RunspaceId              : 79d5a6cc-
FriendlyName            : trlt
```

Comment: try: `Get-MobileDevice -Filter "UserDisplayName -Like '*$fname*'"`

Comment: That worked thanks!

Comment: If you add this as an answer I will check it.

Comment: Added as an answer, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To use a variable in a `-Filter` format your request:

From:
`Get-MobileDevice -Filter {UserDisplayName -Like "*$fname*"}`

To:
`Get-MobileDevice -Filter "UserDisplayName -Like '*$fname*'"`